# copy all the files that end with specific name to another directory

Tags: php

this is how i save image and create thumbnails for it , each image may have different thumbnail with different dimensions

```
    original image :
     abc.jpg

    thumbnails :

    100X150_abc.jpg
    80X80_abc.jpg
etc...
```

now i've made a mistake and about couple hundreds of my images has been saved in the wrong directory 
i know the name of the original images but i'm not sure about thumbnails

all my images have a unique name so i can identify the thumbnails with their name but the beginning part of the name in thumbnails is dynamic .

lets say i want to copy my abc.jpg from `06` directory in the `07` directory

```
rename('images/06/abc.jpg', 'images/07/abc.jpg');
```

but what can i do about thumbnails ? is there a regex like way for doing this ?

like !

```
rename('thumbs/06/^_abc.jpg', 'thumbs/07/^_abc.jpg');
```

basically i want to copy all of the images that end with specific name  ( like `_abc.jpg`) to another directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`glob()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function supports `*` as wildcard (but no full regex support). It returns an array of matched file names:

```
$from = '/absolute/path/thumbs/06/';
$to   = '/absolute/path/thumbs/07/';
chdir($from); // in this way glob() can give us just the file names
foreach(glob('*_abc.jpg') as $name) {
    rename($from.$name, $to.$name);
}
```

The `glob()` function is not so well known, but very handy in such situations because other PHP file functions doesn't support stuff like wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that should work:

```
<?php
$olddir = "./images/06/";
$newdir = "./images/07/";
$files = scandir($olddir);
$count = count($files);
echo $count;
$x = 2;
while($x < $count)
    {
    echo $files[$x];
    $len = strlen($files[$x]);
    $sub = substr($files[$x], $len-7, 7);
    if($sub === "abc.jpg")
        {
        rename($olddir.$files[$x],$newdir.$files[$x]);
        }
    $x++;
    }
?>
```

This will move all the files in 06 folder that end with abc.jpg to 07 folder.

Let me know if it doesn't work.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename('images/06/*abc.jpg', 'images/07/*abc.jpg');` and if you want just the Thumbnails: `rename('images/06/*_abc.jpg', 'images/07/*_abc.jpg');` btw if you want all files that begin with abc use `abc*.jpg`

Comment: If you aren't sure, why would you post it as an answer? Use comments.

Comment: I cant comment on your Question because i dont have 50 reputation.